# Trigger to insert data from source table and another table

Tags: mysql, variables, triggers

I'm using mysql 5.5 and I'm trying to define a trigger.

Here are the tables I have.

```
+------Table1------+ SOURCE: The one which pulls the trigger
+ id | post_title  +
+------------------+
+ 1  | title1      +
+ 2  | title2      +
+------------------+
```

```
+------Table2-------+ Where I need to get the information. 
+ id  | nicename    + Note: Table1.post_title = Table2.nicename
+-------------------+
+ 99  | title1      +
+ 86  | title2      +
+-------------------+
```

```
+----------Table3---------------+ DESTINATION: Where I need to insert
+ id  | meta_key  | meta_value  + Note: Table1.id = Table3.meta_value
+-------------------------------+       Table2.id= Table3.id
+ 99  | hub_page  |        1    +
+ 86  | hub_page  |        2    +
+-------------------------------+
```

This is the query I wrote but it returns: *#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6*

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER 'trigger_name' AFTER INSERT ON 
'table1' FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE user_id int;
    SELECT id into user_id from table2 where(table2.nicename = new.post_title);
    INSERT INTO table3(id,metakey,metavalue) VALUES(user_id,'hub_page',new.id);
END$$;
```

Comment: could you explain a bit what you are trying to do. Note : you can  not do insert/update/delete on the same table where the trigger is running and in your case its on table3 and you have an insert statement in the same table within the trigger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your trigger definition which say run it after insert on table3 ,but in your question it seems that you need to run it after insert on table 1 ,comments for table1 *The one which pulls the trigger* so i assume you need to insert a row in table 3 when insert happened on table1 and in trigger you need to fetch data from table2 for this you can rewrite your trigger as

```
CREATE TRIGGER new_table1_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON 
`Table1` FOR EACH ROW 
INSERT INTO table3(id,meta_key,meta_value) VALUES(
  (SELECT id  from table2 where table2.nicename = new.post_title LIMIT 1),
  'hub_page',
  new.id);
```

In below demo you will notice that i have used any standalone inserts for table3 all inserts are done by trigger

### [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9c3e7)

> Note you are using trigger for insert only so it will only work for
>   inserts,but if you update the data of table1 then table3 will not be
>   updated for this you will need an update trigger too
>
> Also don't use single quotes for table/column names instead use
>   back-ticks to escape reserved keywords